# Query to Fetch Data from Database

Tags: sqlite

I am fetching data from SQLite database using following query:

```
SELECT p.sent,
       e.*,
       e.no _id
FROM ecare e 
LEFT OUTER JOIN pweb p ON e.h_id = p.h_id
WHERE (ant = 'N' or ant = 'D') 
GROUP BY e.h_id
ORDER BY p.sent
```

By using the above SQLite query, I am getting all the records belonging to `sent` (where sent = 1 and sent = 0).

Now, I would like to get only those records from database, where sent status is `sent = 0`. (In short, I don't want to fetch all the records belonging to sent, or records where `sent = 1`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with below query ?

> SELECT p.sent,e.*, e.no _id from ecare e LEFT JOIN pweb p ON
>   e.h_id=p.h_id WHERE (ant = 'N' or ant = 'D')  AND p.sent = '0' GROUP
>   BY  e.h_id

Comment: I have tried same way, but did not get any data whereas I have few data in my database where sent = 0... what's the reason why I am not getting records those belongs to sent = 0

Comment: tried yet not done ... actually before posting here I tried these ways, but did not get any success, but when you shown same way so i thought i must one more time...

Comment: query is simple there is no issue.. make sure you have data in database...

Comment: Hey bro sorry for late response, but I just checked this code in my app, it works, but still I have a small issue, like : I have 2 records in table where sent = 0 but I am getting only one record not both the records... please let me know where I am doing mistake ? both have same h_id = 700

Comment: If you want duplicate record which have same h_id then remove this **GROUP BY e.h_id** from query

Comment: buddy If I remove GROUP BY e.h_id then I am getting each and every record (even where sent = 1) why ? @NiranjPatel

Answer (score 0):

Check below query for your question:

```
   return db.rawQuery("SELECT p.sent,e.*, e.no _id from ecare e LEFT OUTER JOIN pweb p ON e.h_id=p.h_id WHERE (ant = 'N' or ant = 'D')  AND p.sent = '1' GROUP BY  e.h_id  ORDER BY p.sent ", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already filtering on the `ant` column.

Adding a filter for `sent` works the same way:

```
SELECT ...
...
WHERE (ant = 'N' OR ant = 'D')
  AND sent = 0
...
```